# Create python virtual environment based on python source code

Tags: python, python-venv

I need to create python virtual environment from scratch. Of course, I've read
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

But I need to fill `requirements.txt` with package names specific to particular module (e.g. if `*.py` file contains `import psycopg2`, `requirements.txt` should contain `psycopg2`). I think I need something to extract dependencies from certain `.py` file.
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: `.py` file is just a bunch of imports, it has no way of knowing versions of libraries and dependencies. The most straightforward way is to make a clean virtual environment (say using Anaconda), install only the necessary libraries after which the program will run correctly, then do `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to generate the file

Comment: The `requirements.txt` is a file that IMHO should be carefully maintained by hand. You can use `pip freeze` but that will freeze all levels of dependencies and you will most likely miss important updates on the lower levels.